# Why is ValueChanged being called on startup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Im still getting used to the windows phone environment so lots of googling as I go and whatnot. I've been stuck on something for a couple days now and I give it a break, do something else and come back to it. 
My app would crash on opening due to nullpointerexepctions. The code that popped this up was inside a function which is only ran when a slider is changed

the function is

```
    private void changeVolume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Volume = (double)changeVolume.Value;
    }
```

and it comes up with myMediaElement as the problem saying its null. If i breakpoint past this everything works fine. Is there a way to stop this being called on open?

Comment: Add more code: where and how are instancing the media element variable?

Comment: I don't know why it is called - maybe you are setting an initial value and that triggers it? - but a simple workaround is to just check `if(myMediaElement != null)` before trying to change the `Volume`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you got this event when the UI was being constructed. If you have the `changeVolume_ValueChanged` attached in XAML, there's high chance that **any random** component will be not present yet. For example, `myMediaElement` can be null (i.e. because it's defined further down in XAML that yout `changeVolume`) etc.

The simplest thing is, just add null checks:

```
private void changeVolume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if(myMediaElement != null)
        myMediaElement.Volume = (double)changeVolume.Value;
}
```

(btw. the `changeVolume` won't be null since it is its handler)

More complex solution would be to register that handler only after the whole UI got initialized. But,  it can get complex if you use templates and I don't suppose it's really worth that here.

Comment: I can add to this, what order is important in xaml. You can try to fix it by reordering, but generally you have to know about that and either *predict* (by checking for `null`) or *avoid* (by not triggering event in xaml). Binding works great to solve such issues. In `MVVM` ViewModel is created earlier, initialized and only then view pops up with all its events (typically behaviors).

Comment: I figured as much. I tried removing any default values but it makes them anyway. I tried reordering the xaml too but then things just started getting silly. (theres more code in that function that I stated and moving one section just broke another). I guess i'll just have to stick to checking is ANYTHING is null before using it

Comment: @Box: Yep, that's right. Sinatr has much point there, but if you don't use ViewModels (and it seems you are not), there's really very little more left than those !=null checks. You could get "smart" and, for example, remove the handler from XAML, and add some binding/observer/listener that will check when MediaElement starts existing, and that bnd/obs/lst would attach the `changeVolume_ValueChanged` only after it noticed the MediaElement but .. this will spaghettize really soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for null first:

```
private void changeVolume_ValueChanged(object sender, 
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (myMediaElement != null) myMediaElement.Volume = (double)changeVolume.Value;
}
```